# Ecto not allowing fragment parameter for mysql fulltext search

Tags: mysql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am trying to implement fulltext search in ecto with a fragment. However, it is throwing an error that it won't allow me to use the parameter for search term.

> parameters must be of length 1 for query %Mariaex.Query

```
ZB.Repo.all(
  from contact in ZB.Contact,
  where: contact.account_id == ^account_id,
  where: fragment("MATCH (name,email,phone,address_1,city,state,postal_code) AGAINST ('?*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)", ^search_term)
)
```

Comment: Does this work: `fragment("MATCH (name,email,phone,address_1,city,state,postal_code) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE)", ^(search_term <> "*"))`?

Comment: yes, thank you so much! can you add that as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`?` in `fragment` is not plain string substitution. You need to append the `*` outside the fragment SQL, and the fragment SQL should have just `(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)`.

Change:

```
fragment("... AGAINST ('?*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)", ^search_term)
```

To:

```
fragment("... AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE)", ^(search_term <> "*"))
```